# open('....", 'w+') does not create a new file

Tags: python, file

I'm using:

```
import os
path = os.chdir("/my/path")

Websites = ["list", "of", "websites"]


#print(os.getcwd()). -gives the correct result
#print(os.listdir()) -shows my other files, both are correct

def CreateFiles(Websites):
    for W in Websites:
        f = open(W + '.txt','w+') #w+ should open it because it doesn't exist right?
        f.write(W)
        f.close()

CreateFiles(Websites)
```

but i get the error `No such file or directory: 'list.txt'`

Am i missing something? every example i see uses `open(name, read or write argument)`. 
I'm using python 3 on mac.

Comment: I don't get that error when I run this code.  Are you sure this is the exact code you're using?

Comment: Is your user able to write into `/my/path` ?

Comment: I changed the names, like the list of websites contains web addresses, path contains a path etc, but yes its copied and pasted.

Comment: Does `Websites` contain strings that have slashes in them?  Some characters aren't allowed in filenames, and `/` is one of them.

Comment: I'm not sure Jona, do you mean like chmod? i'm writing to this location using `python ./file.py > output.txt` but not from the python file itself. How do I check that this is possible?

Comment: yes john, i was thinking this might be a problem, but wouldn't be because of the string. they're like `["https://www.website.com/","...."]`

Comment: That is exactly the problem.  If you try to create a filename that contains slashes, the slashes are interpreted as a directory.  The directory `https:/www.website.com` does not exist on your computer, so you get that error.

Comment: thanks for the tip, it is exactly that. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

Answer code:

```
import os
path = os.chdir("/my/path")

Websites = ["https://www.website.com/","https://www.Anotherwebsite.com/"]


#print(os.getcwd()). -gives the correct result
#print(os.listdir()) -shows my other files, both are correct

def CreateFiles(Websites):
    for W in Websites:
        P = W.split('.')[1]
        f = open(P + '.txt','w+')
        f.write(P)
        f.close()

CreateFiles(Websites)
```

this creates files of website.txt and Anotherwebsite.txt